# throw new BSONError Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters ,match not working in aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, aggregation-framework

`var objectID=require('mongodb').ObjectId`

```
router.get('/view-ordered-products/:id',async(req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.params.id)
  let orderProducts=await userHelpers.getOrderedProducts(req.params.id)
  res.render('user/view-ordered-products',{orderProducts})
})
```

```
getorderedproducts function is as folllows:

getOrderedProducts:(id)=>{
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {      
            const cartItems = await db.get().collection(collection.ORDER_COLLECTION).aggregate([
                {
                    $match: { _id:new objectID(id) }
                },
                {
                    $unwind:'$products'
                },
                {
                    $project:{item:'$products.item',quantity:'$products.quantity'}
                },
                {
                    $lookup:{
                        from:collection.PRODUCT_COLLECTION,
                        localField:'item',
                        foreignField:"_id",
                        as:'product'
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project:{
                        item:1,quantity:1,product:{$arrayElemAt:['$product', 0]}
                    }
                }
               
            ]).toArray()
            console.log(cartItems)
            
            resolve(cartItems)
               })
```

here the `_id` cannot be matched with `new objectID(id)` to access the collection from mongodb database
it is showing an error `throw new BSONError('Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer');`

I have tried consoling the id obtained from params and it is a string

how can i match the id from the database

please help

Comment: What's a sample value of `id` as logged by the code that attempts to build an ObjectId from it?

Comment: '64fab949704eb8f97173d0a1'

Answer (score 0):

the quotes was also being passed through the url,it should look like this
**http://localhost:3000/view-ordered-products/64fab9e6849734d04c71fd3b**
not,
**http://localhost:3000/view-ordered-products/'64fab9e6849734d04c71fd3b'**